# Avoid jquery function for all the content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with 20 rows. In each row there is an element

```
<p class="exp-date">'.$cust->Expiration_Date.'</p>
```

This element is going to be repeated and return different values but in a lot of rows return 0001-01-01.
I want to hide this content so I wrote this in javascript

```
var exp = $(".exp-date").val();  
var exphide = '0001-01-01';
    if(exp = exphide) {
        $(".exp-date").html('');
    }
```

and also have tried this

```
$('.exp-date').each(function() {
        if(exp = exphide) {
            $(".exp-date").html('');
        }
    });
```

But in both cases apply the jquery on the first row and modify everything not only where the statement is declared.

Someone any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use Double equal to or Triple equal to. Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  == and "this", else it will point to all classes. Code shown below

```
    var exphide = '0001-01-01';
    $('.exp-date').each(function() {
        if(this.innerHTML == exphide) {  //this.innerHTML
            $(this).html('');  //this.html..else will point to all classes
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

You're using assignment in `if` statement. The condition `exp = exphide` will always evaluate to `true` and the code inside the `if` statement will execute for all the elements.

Change

```
if(exp = exphide) {
```

to

```
if(exp == exphide) {
```

or

```
if(exp === exphide) {
```

Also, use `text()` instead of `html()` to get the date, and use `trim()` on it to remove extra spaces before comparing.

Use `this/$(this)` inside the `each` to get the innerText of the current element.

```
$('.exp-date').each(function () {
    if ($(this).text().trim() == exphide) {
    //  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        $(this).html('');
        // ^^^^
    }
});
```

Comment: Note that you are missing the `this` keyword! `$(this).html('');`, `$(this).text('')`, or better `$(this).empty()`

Comment: @Vohuman I've added that in the last code snippet, can you please check again

Comment: sorry man, dont work (continue applying for all p) but a guy gave me the solution!!! I will post it

Answer (score 0):

First you should correct the syntax in the if condition and then try the below code. When you are using "each" for looping you should pass index and value to the callback function as shown below. Then you can achieve the desired result.

```
var exphide = '0001-01-01';
$('.exp-date').each(function(index, value) {
        var exp = $(value).text(); 
        if(exp == exphide) {
            $(value).html('');
        }
    });
```

I suggest not to remove the content from table cell instead you can hide. Hope this helps.